# Angular 6: given ElementRef, can I get ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular

Template

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Directive

```
constructor(vc: ViewContainerRef, el: ElementRef, svc: MyService) {}

useService() {
  this.svc.doWork(vc, el);
}
```

So the service needs both a `ViewContainerRef` and an `ElementRef`.  Do I have to pass both? Is there a way to derive the view container from the element ref? If so I would only need to pass `ElementRef` to the service, and it would fetch the view container from it.

Alternatively, can `ElementRef` be derived from `ViewContainerRef`?  Seems impossible since I assume a single view container can have multiple elements.

Comment: Whats wrong with constructor injection?

Comment: @Antoniossss Not sure I understand why you're asking.  Either way I'll be using injection. Just wondering whether i'm duplicating things that could be simplified. The simplification would have a positive knock-on effect elsewhere in my application.

Comment: What I am wondering, eg vc.getElementRef(something) or the other way around would have such impact that it is worth doing "research" for

Comment: @cgTag just post the answer that I would like to, but anyway, be careful when you passing DOM elements around, its very bad practice and open to XSS atacks. You didnt mentioned the goal of that, but its just a side note.

Comment: @dAxx_ no, it does not open you to cross-domain scripting attacks.

Comment: We tell people not to access DOM elements directly, because it often breaks server-side rendering. That is why we use `ElementRef` as a wrapper so we can inject a virtual DOM library when rendering on the server.

Comment: @cgTag, direct access to DOM elements does do that. you may read the docs.

Comment: I didnt say it automatically do that, but it surely can, depends on the use. As I said, its only a side note.

Comment: @dAxx_ ha no problem. If you happen to know a URL to the docs that mention XSS. I would like to read it. It's news to me.

Comment: @cgTag, https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#security-risk Plus, you can read more about in the security section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the element reference from the view. They both reference the same DOM element.

```
constructor(vc: ViewContainerRef, el: ElementRef, svc: MyService) {
     console.log(vc.element.nativeElement === el.nativeElement);
     // prints true
     this.svc.doWork(vc, vc.element);
}
```